# How can I add a javascript loader that will always show when the DOM is "waiting"?

Tags: javascript, spinner

I want to create a spinner for when the DOM is loading like depicted in the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a loading image from http://www.ajaxload.info/

Add a div that will display progress with display:none css by default

```
   <div id="progress" style="display:none;">
            <img src="../images/ajax-progress.gif" alt="Loading please wait..." style="display:block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto"/>
            <span>Please wait while loading records...</span>
     </div>
```

In your javascript function do something like this

```
function GetData()
{
  //show loading div 
   $('#progress').show();
   $.ajax({
      url: 'ajax/test.html',
      success: function(data) {

      //Hide the progress div if loading data is done
      $('#progress').hide();
      }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I do is, first thing the page does is to show the spinner, and then remove it with an window.onload event.

Comment: Agreed. By default show the loading gif. Then once the movement you are referring to has stopped, you hide the gif and show your content.

Comment: well this has a couple of votes -- sounds like the correct approach. could someone please write some code that would demonstrate how to do this? I'm a newbie and don't really understand much. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an animated gif that overlays the window and remove it when the document is ready.  This will break clients which don't have javascript enabled.

Comment: could you show some code that would demonstrate how that is done?